# I can't display a module in Prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop

I have a problem about displaying a module in front-office when it was grafted.
 
Via the back office, I can graft the module on the hook that interests me, but when I display the front office, my module refuses to display. (No error, in short, everything looks good, but the contents of the tpl file is not displayed).

Comment: Hello. Try to put some source code examples in your question so we can help you. Good luck.

Comment: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module

Answer (score 3):

To display something on Prestashop via custom module, please make sure following things has been followed:

1. Your module must be installed.
2. If you are using hooks in your module to display something or performing any action then those hooks must be registered with your module. Otherwise, Prestashop will not execute hook content of your module.